# In label newline character is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i have the code like this

```
<label class="floating">
<input name="role[permissions][]" type="checkbox" value="project_reopen
asd">
        Project reopen
Asd
        </label>
```

In my Ruby code I put the value like this

```
puts 'project_reopen'+"\n"+'asd'.to_s.humanize
```

The value is displaying the line break but in view its not working

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.c]om/I7NDj.png

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, like breaks are different. You should use `<br>` for that purpose:

```
<input name="role[permissions][]"
       type="checkbox"
       value="project_reopen<br>asd">
```

You should not expect any whitespace to be preserved in HTML as typed. Conseq spaces will be squeezed, etc.

To print the string that comes from not trusted source (like DB,) one should explicitly tell Rails it’s fine to use it as is:

```
  value="<%= @string.html_safe %>"
```

Comment: Value is dynamically coming from the database. Actually I added the newline character. But its not working in the view not in the checkbox value.

Comment: If i give <br  /> its coming like this Project reopen<br  />Asd

Comment: If it comes from DB, you should use `html_safe` or like, I will update my answer.